# Fancybox keeps opening in new window! Why?

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I exactly copied the code from fancyapps.com and changed the folders to the right ones but it still is not working.

when i check the console for errors it says:
"syntax error: missing } before statement" at 27:29

this is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="de">

<head>
  <title>Gallery</title>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="innovate.ico" rel="icon">

  <!-- Add jQuery library -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

  <!-- Add fancyBox -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

  <!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <h2>Gallery</h2>
  <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="gallery\bild_1.jpg">
    <img src="gallery\bild_1_klein.jpg" alt="bild1" />
  </a>

  <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="gallery\bild_2.jpg">
    <img src="gallery\bild_2_klein.jpg" alt="bild2" />
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i made working example. checkout [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-fog-c1gv2?file=/index.html)

> download and run it in your local if it shows any error in
> codesandbox. it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Gallery</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="1_b.jpg"><img src="1_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="1_b.jpg"><img src="1_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```